# Best way to keep Azure Postgres in sync with Azure SQL

Tags: postgresql, azure-sql-database

My team has a pretty dedicated Azure SQL for the use of pretty much everything.

For our web application, however, we use Azure Postgres (it's a Django app running on Linux App Service).

The data engineers usually only work on the Azure SQL DB. So what's the best way to have real-time movement of data from Postgres to Azure SQL database?

So far, the only option I have in mind is to have a Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to do the copy job. But apparently it's not real time.

Many thanks!

Comment: You could create a pipeline to copy data from Postgres to Azure SQL database with upsert(update or insert) operation. Schedule Trigger the pipeline run. Just for now, we can not do the real time data sync with Azure SQL database and Azure Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I searched and per my experience, there isn't a way to sync the data between Azure Postgres and Azure SQL database. Even the Azure SQL database Data Sync also have the 5min delay.

As you said, we could create a Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to do the copy job. Using `upsert` opreation in the Azure SQL sink settings.

Run the pipeline first to make data same in Azure Postgres and Azure SQL database. Then create a schedule trigger(ervey 5 or 10 min) to execute the pipeline. The may achieve the data sync.

Comment: thanks Leon. Do you know some of the benefits of using the `upsert` operation? Why don't we delete the data as a pre-copy script and then start the copy data activity?

Comment: @KelvinNguyenLe `upsert` means update and insert. If the data changed in Source, then update it in Sink. If there is new data, then insert the new data. We don't need to delete all the data.

Comment: by the way, do you think `upsert` will have a better performance than `delete` then `insert`?

Comment: I think it should. When the data will be larger, every time we delete all the data, the copy active will take a long time.